# Android WebView - JavaScript Memory Leak

Tags: java, javascript, android, memory-leaks, android-webview

I am having an issue with Javascript in WebView (enabled using webview.getSettings().setJavascriptEnabled(true); )  The HTML pages with embedded Javascript loads and displays properly, however, what I am also doing is constantly refreshing the screen every 10 or 30 seconds.  When I go into the shell of my test device (MK808 mini-tv) I use "dumpsys meminfo" in order to see the memory of the processes.  Displaying the memory of my app's process every 5 seconds I can see that whenever the page refreshes, the app's memory usage jump multiple (4-10) megabytes.  This continues for around 30 minutes or so until the app crashes with a Fatal Signal 11 error in the WebViewCoreThread, with no stack trace.

Constant Increasing Memory (started at around 15000kb):

[image]

---

None of these memory issues or errors occur when javascript is NOT enabled.

I clearCache(true) and freeMemory(), as well as every other database and cache clear, every single time before I refresh.

I have also tried destroying the WebView after each refresh and creating a brand new one, to no avail.

I can easily remake this issue by just making a new Application project and making a webview that reloads based on a handler controlling time..This seems like it should be a widespread issue but I can't find anything on the subject.  Could it be my device?

Thanks in advance for the help, I'll be glad to add more information as needed!

Answer (score 0):

try to add this also :

```
  //Injects the supplied Java object into this WebView. The object is injected into the 
    //JavaScript context of the main frame, using the supplied name. This allows the 
    //Java object's public methods to be accessed from JavaScript.
    WebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow when I'm at my dev PC.  One question though, how does making the current Activities methods available to the Javascript free up the memory it seems like Javascript is taking up?

Comment: After testing this shows not to really do anything... Thank you for the help though

Comment: Have you got this figured out?

Comment: Wow hi, ya, we ended up testing on other devices and some had the issue while others didn't. We ended up picking a final device that did not exhibit this memory leak.